# Font of equations globally

Tags: fonts, equations

I have the problem, that I write in sans serif and I don't want any serif fonts in my equations. I used the font tgadventor. So, now I had to set every character in"\text{}" environment in my equations. Not good. 
So I changed to a mathfont, "arev". Problem: I don't get the sans serif output in equations like demonstrated on the webpage http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arev/.

Following code:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage{arev}                                                   %%sans serif with math support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
 \usepackage{placeins}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{floatflt}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
 \usepackage{appendix}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{paralist}
 %\usepackage{flafter}
 \usepackage{ifthen}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,format=plain,textfont=small,labelfont=bf,labelformat=simple,labelsep=endash]{caption}



 \begin{document}

test \\
$tees$ \\
\begin{equation}
test
\label{eq:test}
\end{equation}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get my global sans serif font?

Comment: You should reduce your code leaving out every package that does not influence in your problem. That way you make the job easier for us. In particular, you get the math from `mathptmx`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't sure which package causes it, so I did not get rid of any. Sorry for that. Now I will have to have a look why I included this package, I think it had a reason. Can I change fonts in mathptmx?

Comment: Well, if you don't know, just trial and error deleting them one by one until you find the wan that causes the error, at least those which don't cause the error could be easily deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You are loading the `mathptmx` which changes the math font. If you delete it, the math font remains untouched and is the expected from `arev` package.